# Javascript "<body onload=...>" in Drupal

Tags: javascript, drupal, onload

I'm trying to integrate a [javascript library for drag&drop on tables](http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-content/) into one page of my custom Drupal module. I've included the js file using `drupal_add_js`, but I don't know how to initialize it.

The documentation for that library states that an init function should be called like

```
<body onload="REDIPS.drag.init()">
```

How would I do that in Drupal? Or has Drupal some better way of initializing the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal has its own mechanism for this, involving adding a property to `Drupal.behaviors`. See this page: http://drupal.org/node/205296

```
Drupal.behaviors.redipsDragBehavior = function() {
    REDIPS.drag.init();
};
```

From the linked page:

> Any function defined as a property of
>   Drupal.behaviors will get called when
>   the DOM has loaded.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected there was a Drupal way of doing it but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Didn't know about the Drupal javascript stuff. This is great to know.

Comment: If REDIPS.drag.init() doesn't, you should add your own check to avoid multiple initlization. Behaviors function are called each time a element is added to the page through JavaScript and not only on page load. Something like Drupal.behaviors.redipsDragBehavior = function() { if(!argument.callee.init) {
    REDIPS.drag.init();
    argument.callee.init = TRUE;
}};

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding another drupal_add_js call in the same function as your other add_js:

```
drupal_add_js('REDIPS.drag.init();','inline','header',true);
```

The last param "true" is to defer the execution of the script.
I hope that helps in some way!